# Magento : updating cart items count always returns 0

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I am trying to display the number of items added to the cart with ajax. and the value displayed is always 0.

**Here is what my ajax call looks like  :**

```
$(".btn-cart").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
                url: 'update_cart.php' ,

                type: 'GET',

                success : function(data)
            {
                $("#cart_items_count").text(data);
                $("#cart_items_count").show();
            },

                error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }


        });

 });
```

**update_cart.php code looks like this:**

```
    include 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::init();
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $nb_items = count($cart->getAllItems());
    echo(strval ($nb_items));
```

The value returned to the ajax function is always 0. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does `var_dump ($cart->getAllItems());` output?

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. it returns array(0){}